Doping density dependence on effective density of states Si pn junction
I would like to know how the doping density influences the effective density of states in a pn junction. For example the classic relations used to determine this is
$$N_c = 2\left(\frac{2\pi m_n^* k_B T}{h^2}\right)^{3/2}$$
and
$$N_v = 2\left(\frac{2\pi m_p^* k_B T}{h^2}\right)^{3/2}$$
for conduction and valence band respectively.
This does not explicitely depend on doping density but if I am correct the derivation of this equation uses a free electron gas for the density of states which might, for high doping densities, not be appropriate to use anymore. Therefore I would like to know what would happen if you go to high doping densities (in my case n doping with such that $n\approx 10^{20} \ \text{cm}^{-3}$.

At very high doping densities, the shown effective density of states formulae usually don't hold anymore because the wave functions of the discrete energy states close to the conduction or valence band edges of the dopants start to overlap and form energy bands themselves, which finally merge with the conduction or valence band states described by the simple formulae. This also causes the phenomenon of "band gap narrowing" at high doping densities.
Furthermore, at high dopant densities the Fermi level moves into the conduction or valence band so that the carrier occupation statistics has to use the Fermi-Dirac distribution and is no longer approximated by the Boltzmann distribution, which is assumed in the simple density of states formulae.

Thanks for the explanation. Do you also know if there are approximations to account for these effects in the effective denisty of states when doping levels become so high?

For the case of degenerate doping, where the Fermi level edges into the conduction or valence band, there are formulae for the the conduction and valence band occupation using Fermi-Dirac integrals. For the case of dopant band formation and effective conduction/valence band edge changes, i.e., band gap narrowing, I am not aware of simple formulae describing it. One  should best consult the scientific literature on this very special question. This question is probably best answered by experiments.

@willempie You can find the formulae for the effective densities of states using the Fermi-Dirac integrals, e.g., in the book S.M. Sze, Physics of Semiconductor Devices. At doping densities of $n\approx 10^{20} \ \text{cm}^{-3}$ they might still be applicable.

@willempie In tunnel diodes typical doping levels are in this range. You can probably find useful approximations or theoretical treatments for the impurity states band densities of states in papers modeling tunnel diodes.
